# Memory mapping files on file share faster than reading streaming?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-mapping, fileserver, san

I'm wondering what stresses a fileserver more. 
A) reading and processing a file via a ifstream with large buffer size
B) memory mapping the file and then read and process it.

It feels like processing it using a ifstream only makes a few io calls to a file server, while reading it using a memory map this means a lot more io has te be handled by the server.

Since we have a lot of users (1500+) accessing the files on the server and querying multiple times per second I want to make sure that we will not stress the server too much.

We are using a windows 2013 fileserver with SAN storage connected.

Hope the question is clear!

Comment: Are you talking about reading or writing? Answer heavily depends on that.

Comment: Hi, sorry for (very) late reply, but have been on holidays! I'm talking about READING from the fileshare using memory maps!